# Can players from other platforms see my custom skin?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering if the skins that I imported with the Windows 10 and Android editions of Bedrock Minecraft can be seen by other players using console editions of the game like PS4, Xbox One and Switch.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, other platforms can see Imported Skins even if they can't use it.

Here is Windows 10 with an Imported Skin:

[image]

And this is what a PS4 sees:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If the custom skin was created with the in-game Character Creator, yes. If the custom skin was uploaded to your device, it will not transfer to your PS4™ system. This is also true for Xbox One and Nintendo Switch players.

Comment: I know that imported skins can't be synced, I'm asking if players on consoles can see my imported skin or not.